# With pcAnywhere remote, can I set a default option when doing things such as Alt-Enter to get properties?

Tags: remote-control, pcanywhere

When in pcAnywhere remote control I often use the standard Windows key sequent Alt-Enter to get the properties of an object.  In response you get a dialog with the options, "Execute locally", "Send to host" and "Ignore".

Is there an option to default the setting so you aren't prompted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do in the current versions of pcanywhere.